# Clicking link in embedded PDF opens link in PDF frame

Tags: html, object, pdf, acrobat

I a working on a website that uses an embedded PDF that has some links in it (created via Acrobat) that should send the user to other pages on my site.  In chrome, the links work as expected and I have no problems.  However, in Firefox, the link is opened in the frame that holds the PDF.  The site functions properly, but is now stored inside of this frame until you manually put in a URL into the address bar.

Is there any way that I can make the links in the PDF open up in the window that contains the PDF rather than in the frame containing the PDF?

Here is the code used to create the embedded PDF

```
<object id="embedded-pdf" data="<?php echo $url; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem using javascript.  If there is another way to do it within the links for the PDFs themselves, I would rather use that, but this method works.

To fix this problem, I added some javascript to the header of the page that the PDFs were linking to.  In my case, all the pages are using the same header template, so this was an easy fix.  Below is what I did:

```
$(function() {
    ...
    if (window != window.parent) {
        window.parent.location = document.URL;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't JavaScript, it's JQuery. Right?